# C++ using wstring/wchar_t

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t, wstring

Many times whenever I'm talking with people they are reborning me from using(in DLL projects) wstrings and strings because they consumes more memory than wchar_t array. How's with it? Does same `L"qweqweqweqweqwe"` wchar_t array requires more memory than wstring or it is unnoticeable? Now I'm little confused when I have to convert between Ansi and Unicode(many `new wchar_t temp` and `delete`)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your specific question is.  Can you clarify specifically what you're curious about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical usage you will not see significant difference in the memory usage of `string`/`wstring` and character  arrays. On the other hand, if you use character arrays, your code is liable to be full of bugs and leaks and you'll spend all your time dealing with those.

It is accepted by the entire C++ community that `std::string` is the way to handle strings. Any mavericks that want to use character arrays should be compelled to prove their point with benchmarks. The onus should be on the freaks to prove their point of view.

Answer (score 6):

"many new wchar_t temp and delete"

That is usually a very bad idea. As Stroustrup says, you should generally rely on objects to do the memory management for you (look up RAII). Only use raw pointers if it's *REALLY* necessary and only deep down in your implementation. Prefer the STL, prefer smart pointers, use boost, write new and delete only if you really have to and care about exception safety. Else you will spend most of your time debugging your code.

The answer is: unless you have a really good reason, use the string classes. The difference in memory usage is usually insignificant. Only optimize if the profiler tells you to. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Don Knuth).